A/B testing a Question Assistant within Staging Ground
Update on November 19, 2024: This experiment is now live.

TLDR: We will be exploring a new experiment, within Staging Ground, to understand whether AI can be helpful in evaluating question drafts and providing real-time suggestions for improvement, before questions are submitted to human reviewers. AI WILL NOT be editing users’ content.
As we mentioned in our recent Community Products Roadmap Update, Staging Ground is an area we’ve invested in to improve question success for new askers. Earlier this year we rolled out the core experience—a space where new askers get help from experienced users to improve their questions before posting to the broader community. As a result, we’ve seen question quality improve (as noted here in July, questions that go through Staging Ground have higher success and survival rates than those that don’t, which remains true today).
One challenge askers face today is the time it takes to get feedback from reviewers, and that occasionally a question may not receive feedback at all because there are not enough reviewers available. We have recently implemented several updates to increase reviewer participation (including adding more badges, as well as displaying stats) to help Staging Ground keep up with demand. We are also looking at decreasing the time it takes askers to get reviewer feedback from another angle, utilizing machine learning.
What’s being tested?
We're exploring whether an ML/AI-powered question assistant can provide first round feedback earlier, before it gets to a human reviewer, making the whole process move more efficiently. We will be conducting an A/B test in Staging Ground sometime in November, in which machine learning models will be utilized to evaluate new askers’ question drafts within the Ask Wizard experience, and an LLM will provide real-time suggestions based on the machine learning models’ outputs before they’re routed to Staging Ground. To start, we will be utilizing Google Gemini to power this experiment, but in the future we could work with other models.
To be clear, the Question Assistant will not be editing users’ content. It will be pointing out possible areas of improvement in new askers’ questions and encouraging them to make changes before submitting their question. Our intention is to provide relevant and actionable tips for users as they draft questions.
Half of new askers, within Staging Ground, will get to try the Question Assistant experiment and the other half of new askers will still experience the standard functionality as it is today. The goal of this experiment is to test whether AI can help askers get past superficial problems, so that reviewers can focus their efforts on issues that are deeper or more nuanced. All suggestions made to askers are completely optional.
How will it work?
We are currently approaching this in a two step fashion. First we trained several binary classification models to detect whether or not a question needs certain elements (what we are calling feedback indicators here). The Question Assistant will use machine learning to predict the presence or absence of the four indicators listed below. That information will then be passed to an LLM (Google Gemini for this test), along with the title and body of the question, which will then return feedback for what to improve in the question by customizing a canned response with the context it has.
So we’re not currently using an LLM to do the detection itself, although this approach may evolve based on further testing and research we continue to do.
Question Assistant Feedback Indicators:
1. Problem Definition - The problem or goal is lacking information to
understand what the user is trying to accomplish.
2. Attempt Details - The question needs additional information on what
you have tried and the relevant code.
3. Error Details - The question needs additional information on error
messages and debugging logs (as relevant).
4. Missing Minimum Viable Reproducible Example - The question needs
some code demonstrating the problem in a way that others can
reproduce.
We did some offline testing, including a labeling exercise and research study, to develop the list of indicators which are being used to train our machine learning models. The indicators we are starting with in this experiment are a subset of a broader list coming out of that testing. Other indicators which we might include in future experiments are: formatting, expected outcome, image to code, non-English, and off-topic.
See the right sidebar in the mockup below to get a sense of what the Question Assistant experience will entail. Note that the exact designs are subject to change.

We have done some trials of this process with real Staging Ground questions. For example, with a question about sorting arrays in Python that failed to provide any attempt details. Our pre-canned feedback when this indicator is identified is, "The question needs additional information on what you have tried and the relevant code." This feedback would then be passed into the LLM along with the question title and body to return specific, contextualized feedback. In this case Gemini’s output was, "To improve your question, describe the methods you've tried to sort the array, including code snippets and the results you observed. Mention any specific challenges or unexpected behavior encountered during your attempts."
For the course of this experiment, the question will still go to Staging Ground reviewers before making it onto the main site, whether or not the user has made changes based on the Question Assistant’s suggestions. If this feature is adopted and built upon, we can imagine a future in which some askers are able to improve their questions enough, by fielding tips from the Question Assistant, that they can go directly to the main site – making more space in Staging Ground for users who really need one-on-one support from human reviewers.
What's next?
If this experiment is successful we will conduct a second experiment testing some additional feedback indicators, and then consider expanding the feature to all Staging Ground eligible users on Stack Overflow. The primary metrics we will use to measure in this first experiment success are:

Question approval rates
Average review times

As we have stated in other recent communications, the company remains committed to testing AI/ML thoughtfully and purposefully to support the core values of Stack Overflow: human connection, collaboration, and knowledge sharing. The goal is to build and support a healthy ecosystem of active users and community contributors. This experiment will be tested in a safe, controlled, and transparent approach where humans are always in the loop. We remain open to concluding the experiment early if we find the results unfavorable for any reason.
We will report back on our findings before we initiate the follow up experiment, or consider scaling this feature to all users. What do you think of the success metrics we have laid out for this experiment? Are there others that you think we should consider?

Is this is the "review" part of your experiments ?

Can you please just make Stack Snippets work in Staging Ground first? That's an actual, real, concrete problem, AKA a bug. There should not be vague experiments being done on a product which still has major bugs in it since launch.

@Starship Yes, this is one of the initiatives referenced in that blog post.

Is it capable of determining whether or not it’s even a debugging question and thus needs any of the feedback indicators? (the sample question may be just such a question...)
Is this really just replacing the stuff in the right column? wouldn’t an analog step based wizard do just as well, without the overhead of bringing in ML/LLM to do what a radio button would do?

After testing this, it... doesn't seem to really do anything interesting/useful. I gave it a question that was well received, and it more or less gave me incorrect suggestions repeatedly. It misinterpreted what I was asking and recommended me remove something my question didn't have both initially and when I clicked refresh.
My interpretation of this test is a model was trained on common responses from curators in SG or common suggestions from improvement that were pulled from elsewhere and then was instructed to give suggestions with the question as context. It does definitely attempt to make the suggestion relevant to the question being asked, but it doesn't seem to actually produce suggestions that are relevant to the question being asked, rather, it provides suggestions that may be broadly relevant to many questions that might get asked with a few injections of details from the question... which I'd argue isn't better than regular old guidelines for asking questions.
It might be correct occasionally... but the guidelines are always correct.
Here's an example response:

While the goal of my question was preventing browser timeouts... that's not what the question was asking about, I was asking why a particular feature that solves the specific problem I was having wasn't working the way it should in a specific browser. This was clearly explained in the question (and lead to a quick answer.) While file uploads were the reason I asked this question, i left file uploads out of the question sample code entirely because they weren't necessary to recreate the problem... so the suggestions to do so were nonsense. (it also didn't seem to notice that it was a 1:1 duplicate... but it's not built to do that.)
Now, arguably, this was a poor test of the feature because i provided it with a known good question and maybe if presented with a common low quality question it would provide more relevant suggestions... but, again, simple guidelines would have none of these problems.
Asking the user 1-3 questions prior to allowing them to ask a question to get information about what they're hoping to get an answer for would go a long way toward reducing the number of invalid questions that reach the SG and/or homepage by instead directing users to the correct place for them before they even fill in the title.

I'm personally not negative to ML metrics, but pairing it with genAI output is a monumentally bad idea. The genAI can and will provide bad advice, and can and will be jailbroken on day one. What you say is true though; the current onboarding systems are so bad that even a few options and beefing up the wizard to what it was supposed to be in revision 1 would be much higher impact right now

Actually, not just much higher impact, but also much easier and cheaper to develop, deploy, and maintain, the latter of which is critical regardless of what gets rolled out. Failure to maintain is the reason the U&U bot became useless and eventually got axed, and it's the reason pretty much all the moderation systems struggle. Nothing has been maintained to keep up with the increasing volume, and remains locked in time for a significantly smaller and different site

Is it being jailbroken that much of a problem? It's not like it makes any decisions or anything like that and if users want to use it for something else, that's their thing.

wouldn't it be crazy if they seriously engaged with the wizard frame challenge any of the other times it was brought up before?

We’ve thought about adding a classification step, which is something we are considering for future experiments. We know what is off topic, and what elements tend to be included in high quality on-topic questions, but we are curious to know what, from a user perspective, are the different types of acceptable Stack Overflow questions (besides debugging – for instance troubleshooting Qs, software design Qs, etc)?

The biggest one that comes to mind that doesn't at all work with the current solution is "How do i do X." It helps for such questions to have some code to work with, but it's not always necessary and doesn't need to include an attempt at doing X because that just turns it into a debugging question where instead of people providing high value ways of solving the problem... they tend to just fix the OP's way of solving it which may be suboptimal.

For me, the biggest worry is that you've jumped several steps ahead, right to a Generative AI / LLM solution, likely because that's what The Powers That Be want, not what the community wants.
Machine Learning can be powerful and immensely useful in categorization. But that's where the feedback indicators break down. The identified indicators don't even hit the major problems.
What about questions that don't belong on Stack Overflow because they are off-topic (and perhaps belong on another site) or are one of the categories that should be avoided? Once you've identified that a question is a good fit for the SE format, only then can you progress to other indicators of a good question.
What about other criteria for good questions? I don't disagree with any that you've identified, but they also seem to be specific to debugging questions. There are other criteria: Does the title summarize the problem? Are the tags relevant? Is it written in English (or, for the foreign language sites, their language)? Is the spelling and grammar good? Being able to classify on these categories may be easier and demonstrate the proof of concept workflow a little better.
It seems like these would have made for better steps before you integrate Generative AI technology, which isn't widely accepted here. If you could have demonstrated that you could be able to flag questions that don't belong on SO or started with more generally applicable criteria to all SO questions, then added some additional criteria to aid human reviewers, this would probably be better received. Then, in 6 months or so, once you've validated your ability to apply ML models, you can start to pilot your ability to generate guidance and assistance for the askers.

To be honest, I think there is a point to be made for LLMs for things like that as they could explain why something is (likely) off-topic and would also be able to use tag wikis (or maybe also tell the user which SE site to use if a list of all SE sites was in the prompt without requiring a lot of training specifically for that task - making LLM prompts is way easier than training other ML mechanisms (be it classifiers or something else)). (though I'm not saying LLMs should be used for this, I'd like to stay "neutral" on this until I see the results)

@dan1st It seems like maybe you could consider doing an AB test of whether the LLM-extended explanations are more helpful than some canned ones, but you'd still want to start by figuring out if your non-LLM AI is actually identifying the right issues and whether the canned comments are helpful at all.

@BryanKrause got it perfectly. Maybe LLM-extended explanations are more helpful. But sentiments toward LLMs and Generative AI on SO and the network tend to be negative, so why introduce them when they aren't necessary and you haven't validated the core concepts?

Some of the other indicators you mentioned are on our list to train models for, and test in future experiments. These include formatting, lack of clarity about the desired outcome, image-to-code, non-English, and off-topic.
We’ve started with four indicators, which are all broadly related to context and background the user provides in the question, to keep the experiment’s scope limited to get some early learnings first before iterating.

@Sasha I'd recommend thinking about the order. Things like formatting and images that contain code are universally applicable. But things like error details are limited to a subset of questions that actually have an error. An experiment that is encompassing of more questions seems better.

If you want mods and experienced users to provide feedback you should add a way for those to see the generated suggestions for every post on the staging ground (doesn't matter if they were actually shown to the asker or not). Otherwise this is more of a black box and/or annoying to test.
You really want a qualitative evaluation of the advice the LLM generated, not just metrics on how it affected the reception of the questions. There are plenty of people here that will be happy to tell you if the AI is generating nonsense, but you have to make it easy for them to see what the AI would show the askers.
Your chosen metrics are too indirect and fuzzy, you really need to look at the LLM output first and evaluate if that is good enough.

We will expose the Question Assistant to SO mods about a week after the experiment launches so they can test the tool, and report any feedback they have back to the Mod Teams instance. Testers should keep in mind that the suggestions returned won’t be the same every time (even if you were to copy and paste the same question title and body), due to the non-deterministic behavior in LLM output.
For future experiments we also plan to build a mechanism to capture the asker’s feedback on the suggestions provided, to get a sense of how helpful they found the suggestions to be.

details about opting in to testing this tool can be found here: https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/moderators/q/7414/818

I think you're jumping ahead too quickly. Why not start with something much simpler, maybe even something that wouldn't need AI?
For example, what if you detected thank yous and greetings in posts and suggested to users to remove that. What if you detected non-English posts, and (maybe in the language it was written in) tell the user that SO is an English only site, and point them to the correct site, if applicable. DharmanBot already does a great job of that, actually, and I'd imagine with a team of professionals you could do much better. Or what if you blocked posts that are historically in the 100% accurate zone of SmokeDetector's flag weight and reason count. In 8 years, no post with a flag weight over 373 or a reason count over 7 has ever not been spam. What if you blocked those (and in case some false positive happens, maybe give users an option to request that a review queue or mod review their post). This would, by my estimates, block 30% of the spam that gets posted. I would imagine that these ideas would be much simpler, probably wouldn't even require AI, and would still help the site.
Here's my concern with jumping ahead like this. What if the AI is wrong, as AI often is? Then you are now telling users to add or remove things they shouldn't, and teaching them the wrong thing. Then, if they follow that advice, they will then be told by a bunch of users to not do that. That's confusing and annoying, and if I were a new user and got told to do something and then penalized for doing that thing, I would probably just leave.

They used to try detecting non-English content, but it too had problems. See for example False Positive Spanish Language Detection when Asking Question

@Laurel That was more of a quick experiment with the goal of getting an estimate of how much spanish language content there was. And my idea for this is detecting if, say, 25% or more of the body is not in English, maybe a few other things. Besides, I don't know how DharmanBot works, but it's pretty accurate already. Frankly I think just if DharmanBot thinks its problematic giving a notice to the user in that language (but not preventing them from posting) would be a net benefit.

There's so much (practically innumerable) low-hanging fruit on using regexes to block problematic questions. It's amazing they haven't done any of that despite repeated requests from the community to do so.

@TylerH Yeah. Another thing that I'd love for them to do is block posts that are above Smokey's 100% accuracy rate from being posted.

The objection I have to this critique is that there's a tendency for this sort of piecemeal detection to get messy, difficult to maintain, and inefficient rather quickly; I can understand why that approach would seem unattractive from their perspective.

Thanks for these suggestions, we are considering some of these (i.e. detecting non-English posts) for future experiments.
We will continue to consider multiple approaches to solving user problems with asking Questions, with or without the use of AI.
We hope to learn from and iterate on this experiment, as we see a lot of value in running experiments before we introduce anything onto the broader platform, especially when it comes to AI/LLMs. But as stated in the post, we are open to concluding it early if we have any reason to think it is detrimental to users or the site.

When does the AI response start appearing on the right hand side? I note that it covers the information on the right that is meant to help them understand what to put in the boxes, including the still often missed, but very important "Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images), and format them appropriately." statement.
Will users fed to the AI completely miss these prompts on the right hand side, and only get AI responses? If so, considering the hallucinations Stack Overflow's prior attempts had, my concerns are that it's going to be giving the users some utterly bizarre advice during the initial writing of their post.

For users in the experiment group, the Question Assistant’s suggestions will be displayed in lieu of the current tips in the right side bar. Those in the control group will continue to see the standard tips.

Hmm, us knowing what the OP was informed of feels really important then; if the author of the question (which don't forget is a new asker) is given poor advice by the AI that contradicts that of the reviewers, that is going to be a very poor UX for them.
